# How do I update the data in a mysql table called link in the type column for user_id NULL?

Tags: mysql

I understand almost nothing in sql, help me update the data so that in the **link** table for the **type** column, change the value to **direct**, provided that the **user_id** column is **NULL**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlhEw.jpg)

I only know how to update the entire **type** column, but I don't know how to do with the condition, only for **user_id** is **NULL**

```
Update links set type='direct'
```

Comment: Use a `WHERE` condition, just like in `SELECT`.

Comment: `update links set type='direct' where user_id IS NULL`   You nearly spelled out the exact statement you need in your question  ;)

Comment: I hope this isn't important data. Someone who understands almost nothing should not be updating the database.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm sure he's got it, haha

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

See docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

```
Update links set type='direct' WHERE user_id is null
```